# Searching a string in a file anywhere on PC using Findstr

Tags: command-line, search, file-search, findstr

I have a text (.txt) file located somewhere on my PC that contains a bunch of data, including the following string:

```
Secret Username: ********* 
Secret Password: *********
```

How can I find this file from command-line, using [**Findstr**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)?
I don't know if it's on C: drive or D: drive.

I tried various `Findstr` queries, such as:

```
findstr /s /m /n /i Secret Username C:
findstr /s /m /n /i Secret Username D:
findstr /s /m /n /i /c:"Secret Username"
findstr /s /m /n /r /i .*Secret Username.*
```

but couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findstr /S /M /I /C:"Secret Username" C:\*.txt
```

Comment: It finds hundreds of files (lots of Java files), but there's no way they contain this string. Is it because it doesn't look for the whole string?

Comment: so sorry, there was a mistake, I did an Edit ...

Comment: Do you know if it starts searching from where `cmd.exe` is located or from the path showed in command-line itself (for me it's `C:\Users\amiregelz`)?

Comment: that's why it ends with C:\*.*, you have credentials?

Comment: It doesn't find the file (I waited for more than 5 minutes) :-( Do you have any idea why? Also, please add `/M` to the query since otherwise it shows all the content of each file and it's not a good idea because the file I'm looking for contains a lot of data.

Comment: The /N switch already limits the output to the matching line. Furthermore, the command handles about 1 GB a minute. There's a very rough estimate, but scanning the entire C:-drive typically takes a few hours as opposed to five minutes. You can limit the search to .txt-files for a significant performance boost. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarcksThomas Thanks for the info, after searching for `.txt` only it found the file after 30 seconds.

Comment: @ Marcks Thomas thank you, sorry it didn't see (*.txt) ....

Comment: @MarcksThomas: **/N** prints the line number before each line that matches, whereas **/M** prints only the filename if a file contains a match. Since the file has to be located, /M should result in less lines of output and thus a faster search.